# Update constraints swift layoutIfNeeded doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, layout, constraints

I need to update constraints (height of my CollectionView) when request is done and I have images from server, so height of View also will change.

Result screen

[image]

what I need screen

[image]

My code:

```
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.cvActivity.alpha = 0
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                self.collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.cellWidth * 2).isActive = true

                self.collectionView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
                self.collectionView.setNeedsLayout()
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, basic idea by @J. Doe is correct, here some code explanation (for simplicity i used `UIView`, not `UICollectionView`):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! // link the height constraint to your collectionView
    private var height: CGFloat = 100 // you should keep constraint height for different view states somewhere

    override func updateViewConstraints() {
        heightConstraint.constant = height // set the correct height

        super.updateViewConstraints()
    }

    // update height by button press with animation
    @IBAction func increaseHight(_ sender: UIButton) {
        height *= 2
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded() // if you call `layoutIfNeeded` on your collectionView, animation doesn't work
        }
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to make object of your Height constraint from storyboard

```
 @IBOutlet weak var YourHeightConstraintName: NSLayoutConstraint!


  YourConstraintName.constant = valueYouWantToGive
```

---------OR--------

```
  collectionViewOutlet.view.frame = CGRect(x: 
    collectionViewOutlet.frame.origin.x , y: 
    collectionViewOutlet.frame.origin.y, width: 
    collectionViewOutlet.frame.width, height: 
    yourheightValue)
```

Comment: and not to call setNeedsUpdate and etc?

Comment: @ВладиславФорафонтов dont write that in dispatch async

Comment: @ВладиславФорафонтов  no need to call setNeedUpdate

Comment: @ВладиславФорафонтов use this code in this method of viewLifeCycle  override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() { YourConstraintName.constant = valueYouWantToGive }

Comment: but how my project will know that is time to call override func viewWillLayoutSubviews?

Answer (score 1):

Define a height for your collectionView, create an outlet from that constraint and increase the constant of that constraint and call layoutifneeded in an animation block

Comment: doesn't work for me:
self.collectionViewHeight.constant = self.cellWidth * 2
self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: @ВладиславФорафонтов, i believe you should call `layoutIfNeeded()` at  superview of collectionView?

Comment: @pacification Of what view's must I call layoutIfNeeded? Now I call only in collectionView

Comment: My code now:                
self.collectionViewHeight.constant = self.cellWidth * 2; 
self.view.layoutIfNeeded(); 
self.collectionView.reloadData(); and it doesn't work too

Comment: @ВладиславФорафонтов take a look for my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48150634/2463616